# Dealing with multiple optional arguments in a javascript function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

first time posting, basically doing the Odin project Exercise 04 - removeFromArray excercise:

https://github.com/TheOdinProject/javascript-exercises/tree/main/04_removeFromArray

I have got the first test to pass, however, i have no idea on how to write the program to deal with multiple optional arguments. I know i need to use the ...arg, but do not really understand how to start or what to do, or the general construction of the function, please can someone help me to understand how to go about this? Below is a very poor attempt by me which doesnt work (not even sure if my logic is correct to get the desired output):

```
const removeFromArray = function (array1, ...args) {

    if (args == 3) {
        array1.splice(2, 1);
        return array1;
    } else if (args == 3 || args == 2) {
        array1.splice(2, 1);
        return array1.splice(1,1);
    }
};


console.log(removeFromArray([1, 2, 3, 4], 3, 2));
```

any help or advice on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`args` is an array of arguments. So you just need to filter the original `array` and filter out those elements that are in array `args`:

```
function removeFromArray(array, ...args) {
    return array.filter(x => !args.includes(x))
};


console.log(removeFromArray([1, 2, 3, 4], 3, 2));
```

gives you:

```
[1, 4]
```

Comment: Thank you that works perfectly, and makes sense now to me!

Answer (score 1):

`args` is an array, so you can loop it via `forEach` and remove items from your `array1`

```js
const removeFromArray = function (array1, ...args) {

  args.forEach((arg) => {
    const index = array1.indexOf(arg);
    if (index > -1)
      array1.splice(index, 1);
  });
  return array1;
    
};


console.log(removeFromArray([1, 2, 3, 4], 3, 2, 5));
```

Comment: Thank you I now understanding the logic needed!